# What is the range of the "number of characters read" in fscanf?

Tags: c, scanf

`fscanf()` specifies the `"%n"` directive as a means to write "the number of characters read from the input stream so far by this call to the `fscanf` function" C11dr §7.21.6.2 12.

Let us call this number: `ncount`.

---

The `"%n"` directive may be preceded by length modifiers `hh, h, l, ll, j` and others.  Examples:

```
FILE *stream = stdin;
int n_i;
fscanf(stream, "%*s%n", &n_i);    // save as int
signed char n_hh;
fscanf(stream, "%*s%hhn", &n_hh); // save as signed char
long long n_ll;
fscanf(stream, "%*s%lln", &n_ll); // save as long long
```

> What is type or the minimal expected range of `ncount`?
>   What happens, or should happen, when "the number of characters read from the input stream" is *large*?

My findings:
The C spec appears quiet on the definition of the minimal range/type of `ncount`.  `ncount` is usually saved via `"%n"` which specifies an `int` *destination* though not an `int` *source*.

By experimentation, `ncount` appears to be treated like an `int` or `long` on my platform - no real surprise there.  (My `int/long/long long` are 4/4/8 bytes.) When saving `ncount` to a `long long`, the value saved does not exceed `INT_MAX/LONG_MAX`.  `ncount` could have been `unsigned` for twice the usable range when assigned to `long long`, yet, this is an extreme corner and perhaps not considered by implementors.

My tests below showed no extended range of `ncount` past an `int` range, even when saved as a `long long`.

My interest stemmed from using `"%*[^\n]%lln"` to determine a (extreme) line length.

---

Implementation notes:

GNU C11 (GCC) version 6.4.0 (i686-pc-cygwin) compiled by GNU C version 6.4.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5-p10, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version 0.14 or 0.13

glibc 2.26 released.

Intel Xeon W3530, 64-bit OS (Windows 7)

---

Test code

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int print(FILE *stream, long long size, int ch) {
  char buf[4096];
  memset(buf, ch, sizeof buf);
  while (size > 0) {
    size_t len = size < (long long) sizeof buf ? (size_t) size : sizeof buf;
    size_t y = fwrite(buf, 1, len, stream);
    if (len != y) {
      perror("printf");
      return 1;
    }
    size -= len;
  }
  return 0;
}

int scan(FILE *stream) {
  rewind(stream);
  long long n = -42;
  int cnt = fscanf(stream, "%*s%lln", &n);
  printf("cnt:%d n:%lld ", cnt, n);
  return cnt != 0;
}

int testf(long long n) {
  printf("%10lld ", n);
  FILE *f = fopen("x.txt", "w+b");
  if (f == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    return 1;
  }
  if (print(f, n, 'x')) {
    perror("print");
    fclose(f);
    return 2;
  }
  if (scan(f)) {
    perror("scan");
    fclose(f);
    return 3;
  }
  fclose(f);
  puts("OK");
  fflush(stdout);
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%d %ld %lld\n", INT_MAX, LONG_MAX, LLONG_MAX);
  testf(1000);
  testf(1000000);
  testf(INT_MAX);
  testf(INT_MAX + 1LL);
  testf(UINT_MAX);
  testf(UINT_MAX + 1LL);
  testf(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Test output

```
2147483647 2147483647 9223372036854775807

File length      Reported bytes read
      1000 cnt:0 n:1000 OK
   1000000 cnt:0 n:1000000 OK
2147483647 cnt:0 n:2147483647 OK
2147483648 cnt:0 n:-2147483648 OK  // implies ncount is internally an `int/long`
4294967295 cnt:0 n:-1 OK
4294967296 cnt:0 n:-1088421888 OK  // This `n` value may not be consistent. -1 also seen
         1 cnt:0 n:1 OK
```

[Edit]

With some runs of `testf(UINT_MAX + 1LL);`, I received other inconsistent results like '4294967296 cnt:0 n:1239482368 OK'.  Hmmmm.

Sample `fscanf()` [support source code](http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/lib/libc/stdio/vfscanf.c) uses an `int` for `ncount`.

Comment: I conflicted between voting up for an interesting question and not voting up because, if your input is exotic, you should be writing your own parsing and not using `fscanf`. Nonetheless, I expect the answer is C 2011 5.2.4.1: “The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program…” Your program is not that one.

Comment: I agree with your analysis of the standard.  It does not specify a bound on how large an `ncount` must be supported.  It does specify that the `ll` (and `z` and `t`) length specifiers can appear in an `n` directive, and of course you're right that that describes the size of the receiving variable, not the source count.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Use of `fscanf()` does not know prior to reading if the input is exotic.  The issue is not that the input is exotic, but that `"%*s%n"` is not resilient to exotic input.  For example, `"%1000s%n"` would work with exotic input - as long as `ncount` is at least 10 bit.

Comment: This is exactly why I don't understand why the type expect by `%n` is not a `size_t`. I suppose legacy is the main reason.

Comment: The standard also specifies that the behavior is undefined (for all conversions) if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the destination object.  Inasmuch as I don't see any other qualification on how large an `ncount` is accommodated, I'm inclined to regard it as an implementation flaw if the reported count is bounded by limits smaller than the capacity of the destination object's type.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks for the edit that added a missing `include`.  Yet the cast of `long long` to `size_t` changed functionality with my 32-bit `size_t` as it truncated `4294967296`.  Code amended to not warn and work for sizes up to `LLONG_MAX`.

Comment: @chux My bad, sorry. I didn't cast the good operand. I test with my 64 size_t ^^'. (But that explain a little why in your system the result is -1, scanf must use a size_t type to hold count internally, that surprise me that your size_t is 32bit on a 64bit system. Windows != ♥)

Comment: @Stargateur What was your result with `testf(UINT_MAX + 1LL);`?  (Assuming `unsigned` is 32-bit)  BTW: I am now sure my compiler/library used a 32-bit `int` for `ncount`.

Comment: @chux I get correct output (not -1 or garbage) with both codes (actuel code and my wrong edit) with my 64bit archlinux (`unsigned is 32bit`) https://pastebin.com/3Py5w5cr.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanx.  To a "quality of implementation", your library is better than mine.  OTOH, it might be impractical for your platform to test its limit.  I'll assume it is good for at least about `INT64_MAX` - which should handle extreme code for perhaps 30-40 years given [Moore's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law). ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is type or the minimal expected range of ncount?

The standard does not specify any specific minimum.  It flatly says

> The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed integer into which is to be written the number of characters read from the input stream so far by this call to the fscanf function.

([C2011, 7.21.6.2/12](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12))

This leaves no room for a conforming implementation to store a different number in the destination variable, except inasmuch as the standard specifies for *all* conversions, including `%n`, that

> if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the [destination] object, the behavior is undefined.

([C2011 7.21.6.2/10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10))

> What happens, or should happen, when "the number of characters read from the input stream" is large?

If the pointer corresponding to the `%n` directive is correctly typed for the directive's length specifier (or lack thereof), and if the true count of characters read up to that point by that `scanf()` call can be represented in an object of that type, then the true count should in fact be stored.  Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.